# How to implement the load balancing for jitsi meet?

Tags: video, jitsi, jitsi-meet, videocall, lib-jitsi-meet

We have successfully install the jitsi-meet on Ubuntu Server. We followed the following link

https://jitsi.org/downloads/ubuntu-debian-installations-instructions/

Now we want to Implement the load balancing technique for a large no. of users and conferences.
I followed the https://samynitsche.de/4-install-jitsi-meet-and-configure-load-balancing link for the MUC technique. But it is not working smoothly. I mean it crashed 3rd participant joined the conference then No video face is showing only black is showing. and sometimes it crashed the conference.
No Errors is Logs files.

Any updated steps for load balancing?